# htaccess Redirect Domain and Subdomains to https and including www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have problems to redirecting the url using https

1. www.domain.com to domain.com
2. www.name.domain.com to name.domain.com

The domain is ok, but the subdomain does not.

Here's my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1\.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I'm checking this but it does not work:

```
# redirect www to none-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]

# redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Comment: What happens if you change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1\.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]`?

Comment: Does not redirect the subdomain.

And the domain redirects from www.example.com to www.example.com.example.com, where the second "example.com" is in the code: RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ http: //% 1 \ .example.com / $ 1 [R = 301, NC]

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+).example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I tested it and it works fine but it depend on your settings for sub domains, if your sub domains point to main directory you need to place your htaccess file just in main directory, but if your sub domains point to another directory you have to place your htaccess file in all the directories, you can check it in your host panel

Comment: You are right Danial, for the subdomain works, it is correct.

Thank you very much.